# Retrieve ALL images from URL (internet) and save them locally (sdcard) - Android

Tags: android, url

Well... my application has LOTS of images in the internet. They are stored in folders and subfolders like categories.

Upon the first start of my app, I would like to allow the user to download all this content to his/her internal sdcard.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    URL url = new URL ("www.mysite.com/folder1/subfolder1/anImage.png");
    InputStream input = url.openStream();
    try {
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/myImage.png");
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
```

Okay... the code above allows me to save ONE image from one link.

**How can I retrieve them all?**

Also, is it possible inform the user how many data (MB) will be transfered?

Any help is appreciatted!

Thanks!

Comment: u have a list of images name which u want to download in bulk.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) is a good example and explanation on [how to download images](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). 
You can calculate the size of remote files by following method. Pass array of urls to this method and it will return you the size in bytes.

```
public static int getSize(String[] urls){
    int sizeInBytes = 0;
    for (String string : urls) {
        sizeInBytes += ((int) (new File(string)).length());         
    }
    return sizeInBytes;
}
```

You can also calculate the size of images once they are downloaded on sd-card Pass the directory file (where you have saved all images) to `getSize(...)` method and it will return the size of directory in bytes.

```
String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(basePath +"file/myImageDirectory/");
ClassName.getSize(file);
```

Method to calculate size of Directory.

```
public static int getSize(File directory) {
    return getSize(directory, 0);
}
private static int getSize(File directory,int sizeInBytes) {

    if (directory == null)
        return sizeInBytes;
    if (!directory.exists())
        return sizeInBytes;
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        String[] list = directory.list();
        // Some JVMs return null for File.list() when the
        // directory is empty.
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                File entry = new File(directory, list[i]);
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    sizeInBytes = getSize(entry,sizeInBytes);
                } else {
                    sizeInBytes +=entry.length();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sizeInBytes;
}
```

One `MB=1024*1024`,You can get `SizeInMB` by dividing `sizeInBytes` by size of MB; `sizeInMB=sizeInBytes/MB;`